# Exact integer nullspace of integer matrix?

Tags: julia, linear-algebra

`nullspace(A)` finds a basis for the null-space of a matrix `A`. The returned vectors have floating-point coordinates. If the matrix `A` is an integer-matrix, the basis can be found in integer coordinates.

For example, in *Mathematica*,

```
NullSpace[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3, 4}]]
```

always returns integer vectors.

Is there a way to compute an integer basis for an integer matrix in Julia?

**Update:** I get build errors with `Nemo.jl` (see comments to Dan Getz's answer). In the mean time, is there an alternative?

Comment: Could you help me understand this magic? I ran `NullSpace[RandomInteger[{-10, 10}, {3, 4}]]` on WolframAlpha. It’s saying the nullspace of `[-9 5 3 -9; 0 5 -10 8; -3 -10 7 5]` is `[-56; 440; 639; 310]`, but the matrix-vector product of those two is non-zero? (Specifically it’s `[1831; -1710; 1791]`.)

Comment: @AhmedFasih Try transposing

Comment: It’s a 3x4 matrix, so I’m not sure what to transpose…

Comment: Nemo gives me the right answer 

Comment: @AhmedFasih Sorry, I meant that you should transpose the nullspace matrix before multiplying.

Comment: @AhmedFasih I'm getting an error with Nemo (see my comment on Dan Getz answer)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nemo.jl is a package for algebra in Julia. It has a lot of functionality and should also allow to compute the null space. One way to go about it would be:

```
using Nemo   # install with Pkg.add("Nemo")

S = MatrixSpace(ZZ, 3, 4)
mm = rand(-10:10,3,4)
m = S(mm)
(bmat,d) = nullspace(m)
```

After which `d` is the dimension of the nullspace and `bmat` has a basis in its columns.

Hope this helps (I would be happy to see alternative solutions possibly using other algebra packages).

Comment: I get this error with `Nemo`: ERROR: LoadError: error compiling __init__: could not load library "/opt/julia/v0.4/Nemo/local/lib/libpari"

Comment: Can you print the output of `nullspace` (specifically the null vectors)? Are they integers?

Comment: @becko works for me: `m = S([-9 5 3 -9; 0 5 -10 8; -3 -10 7 5]); (bmat,d) = nullspace(m)` prints out `([65] [288] [300] [195],1)`. So yes, the nullspace vectors are ints and I confirmed that `m * bmat` is the zero vector.

Comment: @becko I had to run: `Pkg.add("Nemo"); Pkg.update(); Pkg.build("Homebrew"); using Nemo`, which took forever, because Julia at each stage kept telling me things needed more compilation or didn’t compile. I’m running julia 0.4.5.

Comment: My results are similar to @Ahmed's. The `[65] [288] [300] [195]` formatting is Nemo's way of printing matrices.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Nemo seems to be what I need, but I can't install it. I tried your suggestions but keep getting build errors.

Comment: I finally got Nemo.jl installed. @AhmedFasih How do I convert the nullspace vectors resturned by Nemo to an ordinary Julia Array?

Comment: I'm trying to do this now for *rational* matrices, but `matNemo = Nemo.MatrixSpace(Nemo.QQ, 3, 4)(matq)` doesn't work, where `matq` is a matrix of Rationals. Can you help me?

Comment: Try replacing `ZZ` in `S = MatrixSpace(ZZ, 3, 4)` with `QQ`, i.e. `S = MatrixSpace(QQ, 3, 4)`.

Comment: @DanGetz It doesn't work, because Nemo has some `convert` functions missing. See https://github.com/Nemocas/Nemo.jl/issues/82. But I figured it out, thanks!

Comment: The code in the answer works (with `QQ` replacement). Looking at the issue, the discussion also provides a partial answer as to how to populate a matrix. If you post the code and the error produced maybe it would help (I see you might have resolved it already, in this case you can share the workaround).

Comment: @DanGetz Basically I made the missing `convert` functions. I did pull requests into Nemo.jl.