# Convert matrix from Nemo.jl to ordinary Julia Array?

Tags: arrays, julia

I copy here the following code snippet from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39257232/855050) as an example:

```
using Nemo   # install with Pkg.add("Nemo")

S = MatrixSpace(ZZ, 3, 4)
mm = rand(-10:10,3,4)
m = S(mm)
(bmat,d) = nullspace(m)
```

Now `bmat` is of type `Nemo.fmpz_mat`. I want to convert it to an ordinary Julia `Matrix{Int}`. I tried `Matrix{Int}(bmat)` but it doesn't work.

See also: https://github.com/wbhart/Nemo.jl/issues/57

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I defined my own `convert`:

```
function Base.convert(::Type{Matrix{Int}}, x::Nemo.fmpz_mat)
    m,n = size(x)
    mat = Int[x[i,j] for i = 1:m, j = 1:n]
    return mat
end

Base.convert(::Type{Matrix}, x::Nemo.fmpz_mat) = convert(Matrix{Int}, x)
```

Comment: I would suggest to the developers of Nemo that they add some conversion methods like these.

Comment: @JeffBezanson There is an issue on github that I linked in the question.