# Determining if the determinant of an NxN integer matrix is even or odd

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, linear-algebra

For a given NxN (0,1)-matrix whose values are all integers, I want to determine if the determinant of the matrix is even (mod2 = 0) or odd (mod2 = 1).

Is there any efficient algorithm? N is as large as 100, so a brute-force O(N!) solution is too slow.

If I do gaussian-elimination and calculate determinant naively, the determinant will be at most 200 digits, so I have to do 200-digit multiplications and divisions.

Comment: I'm not sure what's your issue with `0/0` in Gaussian-elimination. Obviously the answer is the same if you replace all the values in the matrix with their `mod2`. And this might produce a lot of 0 already. But it just means your elimination has less work to do.

Comment: @SergGr Gaussian Elimination includes division, and now if you think about (a, b)=(4, 2) and (2, 2) (not mod 2), a/b is both 0/0 (mod 2) and the answer is zero or one, so you can't determine.

Comment: Is the determinant of a 100 by 100 matrix really too expensive? In my limited experience, LU decomposition on 100 by 100 is doable.

Comment: @AhmedFasih Can LU decomposition use in mod2?

Comment: @square1001, I still don't get your problem. How do you get 4 or 2 if you start with replacing all the numbers with their mod2? And after that you really have only 1 and 0 so why do you need divisions then? You can simply do `add_mod_2` (which is the same as `sub_mod_2`)

Comment: I am probably confused—your question makes me think your matrix elements are integers, so you’d just do LU, evaluate the determinant, and see if it’s even or odd. But are your matrix elements binary (GF2) or something tricky like that?

Comment: @AhmedFasih But if you do normally it uses at most 100! (about 200 digits) and you should do 200-digit multiplications or 200-digit divisions!

Comment: _But if you do normally it uses at most 100! (about 200 digits) and you should do 200-digit multiplications or 200-digit divisions!_ @square1001, that's why you should start with replacing all the values with their mod2. Then all intermediate values in LU calculation can't be any big. Moreover, you can do all intermediate calculations using `mod2` as well.

Comment: @AhmedFasih If you do with floating-point computation, you will cause "error (I think if 64bit eps=1e-15)", and it will judge 10^100 and 10^100+1 is same.

Comment: Can you install and use Julia? Nemo.jl is an algebra package in Julia that allows you to define matrixes over the set of integers and do [LU decomposition](http://nemocas.github.io/Nemo.jl/latest/matrix/#lu-factorisation) on them, and the result should be in integers. In this question, Nemo.jl was used to calculate the nullspace of a matrix over integers: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39255580/exact-integer-nullspace-of-integer-matrix

Comment: @AhmedFasih I want to know algorithm. I am not asking values of determinant.

Comment: Looks like they implement the standard LU but they use Flint for arbitrary-length integers, and calculate the [determinant](http://nemocas.github.io/Nemo.jl/latest/matrix/#determinant) in the usual way: https://github.com/Nemocas/Nemo.jl/blob/2899dbd38adf69ba8bb841b3f2a2d1318ce53572/src/generic/Matrix.jl#L973-L1025 yes, the determinant of a random 100x100 integer matrix was 300 digits long…

Comment: I like the mod 2 suggestion. If you look at the nxn version of the definition of the determinant in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant you can see that the determinant is just a polynomial with all positive powers so if you want to know if it is even or odd you can evaluate it mod 2. Note that when you do gaussian elimination mod 2 you can pack 32 or 64 bits per word and do 32 or 64 xors in one fell swoop just by xoring two words together. If you have a matrix of size 200x200 you might represent each row as 7 or 4 words respectively.

Comment: The integers mod 2 form a field, so you can do Gaussian elimination in it.

Comment: Just curious, why do you want to find that? Hardcore scientific/statistic project, or AI?

Comment: @javaLover Just curious. I just wanted to determine even/odd of complete matching of bipartite graph, and proved that it can calculate for determining even/odd of determinant of a matrix.

Answer (score 2):

Working mod 2 is exceptionally easy. The following is a recursive approach that is based upon the following:

1. If the first column is all 0 then the determinant is 0.
2. If the first column has a 1 in the first row and is 0 below, then the determinant is the same as the determinant of the matrix obtained by removing the first row and first column.
3. Swapping two rows has no effect on the mod-2 determinant. If you weren't working mod 2 you would multiply by -1, but -1 (mod 2) = 1.
4. Replacing a row by a sum of that row and another row has no effect on the determinant.
5. When you add two rows whose first entries are 1 then mod-2, you get a row whose first entry is 0.

A Python 3 implementation:

```
def det2(mat):
    matrix = [[a%2 for a in row] for row in mat]
    n = len(matrix)
    if n == 1: return matrix[0][0]
    #first find a nonzero element in first column
    i = 0
    while i < n and matrix[i][0] == 0: i += 1
    if i == n:
        return 0 #since a column of zeros
    else:
        if 0 < i: matrix[0],matrix[i] = matrix[i],matrix[0] 
    #clear rest of column:
    for i in range(1,n):
        if matrix[i][0] == 1:
            matrix[i] = [a+b for a,b in zip(matrix[i],matrix[0])] 
    rest = [row[1:] for row in matrix[1:]]
    return det2(rest)
```

Tested like:

```
import random

def randMatrix(n,k):
    return [[random.randint(0,k+1) for i in range(n)] for j in range(n)]

A = randMatrix(100,100) #a 100x100 random matrix with entries in 0,1,...,100

det2(A) #takes less than a second
```

The above code is mostly proof-of concept. It is reasonably quick even though Python is an interpreted language. If you use the idea of @mcdowella and pack the entries in 64-bit integer variables and use bit-wise operations, the above code could be modified to work very rapidly in something like C. Furthermore, it is of course easy enough to write it in an iterative rather than recursive form:

```
def det2(mat):
    matrix = [[a%2 for a in row] for row in mat]
    n = len(matrix)
    for i in range(n):
        #first find a nonzero element in column i in row i or below:
        j = i
        while j < n and matrix[j][i] == 0: j += 1
        if j == n:
            return 0 #since a zero will be on final diagonal
        else:
            if i < j: matrix[i],matrix[j] = matrix[j],matrix[i] 
        #clear rest of column:
        for j in range(i+1,n):
            if matrix[j][i] == 1:
                matrix[j] = [(a+b) % 2 for a,b in zip(matrix[i],matrix[j])] 

    #if you get to this stage without returning 0:
    return 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace the odd numbers by 1 and the even numbers by 0. If the new determinant value is odd then the value of the mother determinant is odd else even